# How to upload data-uri files in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter's file upload library expects $_FILES[] before uploading files. If the $_FILES[] is not set, it returns an error.

I am struggling here, because I am getting the POST as JSON and that JSON contains the file as data uri.

How do I use codeigniters native file upload helper for data-uri ?

Comment: Just treat it like you would any other text value

Comment: Maybe you didn't get the context. I am getting the post data, but how do I treat that as file and upload that. I am trying to use CI's native file upload helper. But that is not helping, because that helper expects a $_FILES to upload. As because I am posting the image as data uri, I dont have any $_FILES.

Comment: I don't think you get it... a daturi is a text representation of the image. Show the ajax used to transpose image and send data and

Comment: If you aren't transposing image using canvas api then you are uploading file incorrectly